# How to use a modal form to select from different lists? (Razor pages)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, bootstrap-modal

There are several fields on the page, the values ​​of which are in different lists. I need these fields to call the same "modal fade" block in which data is being populated from different sources.

```
<div id="modalcontainer" class="modal-body">
<ul>
    @{
        string source = "Areas"; // If you change the value, then it works (for example "Regions", Cities, etc.)
        foreach (Net45MVC.Abstract.IIdentifiers c in (dynamic)ViewData[source])
        {
            <li>
                @Html.ActionLink(c.Name, "id", new { id = c.Id }, new { @class = "selectedItem" })
            </li>
        }
    }
</ul>
```

I have verified that the `Razor handler` executes the code on every call to the modal block, this allows configuring the handling. The problem is that there is no way to pass a value from HTML and JavaScript to Razor. So I am looking for other ways.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you should not use Razor code, but completely switch to javascript - it can change the html content. But is it possible for JS to get data from ViewData or ViewBag?

Comment: "But is it possible for JS to get data from ViewData or ViewBag?" You can place those values in a hidden input, and then get those values in javascript with `getElementById(...).value` or with jquery: `$(...).val()`.